# How to get the value from the condition when it was first time true?

Tags: php

I try to get time count in a site. but it cannot work my code.
Here is my code:

```
$page_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$time_start;
if ($page_id === 'question1') {
   $time_start = microtime(true);
}

if ($page_id === 'finish') {
   $time_end = microtime(true);
   echo $time_start . " i m start time";
   $duration = $time_end - $time_start;
   if ($duration) {
      $duration = round($duration, 4);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO elapsed_time(time) VALUES('$duration')";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   }
}
```

$time_start shows null. how can i get this?

Comment: `$time_start` is set only when `$page_id` is question1.

Comment: when it first time set then i want to use every time. how can i get this?

Comment: Do you understand what I've just wrote?

Comment: remove your if condition.just initialize `$time_start = microtime(true);`.and use.

Comment: yes i understand. but when it set then i want to use globally. how can i get this?

Comment: you are declaring $time_start, but not setting it.  So it's going to be null if the condition is not met.

Comment: Are you trying to measure time between different pages that the user navigates? You have to use a session variable to keep values between pages.

Comment: Thanks. @Barmar. this is the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a session variable to keep a variable between different runs of the script.

Call `session_start();` at the beginning of the script, then use `$_SESSION['time_start']` instead of `$time_start`.